# Python--always get "must be str not int"

Tags: python

I want to read in words in a loop until the user types `stop` or `<space>`. When the loop is stopped I want to concatenate and print all the words previously typed by the user (not including stop or space).

```
while True:
    reply = input('Enter text, [type "stop" to quit]: ')
    print (reply)
    if reply == 'stop':
        break
    while len(reply) >3:
        reply=reply+1
        print (reply)
```

For example:

> reply1 is "how"
>
> reply2 is "long"
>
> reply 3 is "has"
>
> reply 4 is"it"
>
> reply5 is "been"
>
> **expect output:** "how long has it been"

Comment: What are you trying to do with `reply+1`?? You can't add ints to strings, and that would be an infinite loop if you did add a string

Comment: What is the input supposed to be? You are trying to add 1 to it `'foo' + 1` makes no sense and python does not allow it. Also adding `reply+reply` is just making the string longer, adding to it will never makes its length less, so the loop will continue forever.

Comment: It is unclear what you want the program to do for the given input `abcdef` what output are you expecting?

Comment: Think about it. `while len(reply) > 3:` What happens if the user types `boop`? `len(reply)` is already > 3, and your loop will never stop in order to go back to getting more input. Learn to understand what the code you're writing actually does, instead of just pounding at the keyboard.

Comment: reply1 is "how" ; reply2 is "long" ; reply 3 is"has" ;reply 4 is"it"; reply5 is "been". concatenate the words.

Comment: @YeiBi: The code above would never get to reply3 being entered, because reply1 + reply2 is already more than 3 characters.

Comment: @YeiBi can you tell us the output you want at each stage, at the moment it's completely unclear what you are trying to accomplish with this code.

Comment: expect output is "how long has it been".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is hard to tell what you want, but based on your edits it looks like you are trying to do something like this:

```
replys = []
while True:
    reply = input('Enter text, [type "stop" to quit]: ')
    print(reply)
    if reply == 'stop' or reply == ' ':
        print(" ".join(replys))
        break
    replys.append(reply)
```

Comment: Thanks for your illustrating.

Answer (score -1):

The question is not clear, but I think what you're saying is that you want to iterate over a number and modify it as the loop, loops. If that is true, the below may help...

```
while True:
    reply = input('Enter text, [type "stop" to quit]: ')

    print (reply)

    if reply == 'stop':
        break

    replyInt = int(reply)

    while replyInt < 100:
        replyInt = replyInt+1
        print (str(replyInt))
```

**EDIT:**

OK, based on your new comments, this may work for you:

```
totalReplies = ""

while True:

    reply = raw_input('Enter text, [type "stop" to quit]: ')

    if reply == "stop":
        print(totalReplies)
        break

    totalReplies = totalReplies + " " + reply
```

OUTPUT:

```
Enter text, [type "stop" to quit]: how
Enter text, [type "stop" to quit]: long
Enter text, [type "stop" to quit]: has
Enter text, [type "stop" to quit]: it
Enter text, [type "stop" to quit]: been
Enter text, [type "stop" to quit]: stop
 how long has it been
```

Comment: It returns -->ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'how'

Comment: OK. reading the comments above, I am confused and way off interpreting your question. Please state expected input and expected output.

Comment: expect output is "how long has it been"

Comment: And the expected input?

Comment: input is desided by the user-->when user input "how" , next is "long", next is "has", then input "it" , the final input is "been"

Comment: @YeiBi you are telling us the input at each stage, but not the output at each stage, you are just telling us the final output. Do you only want to output after the user types `stop` or after a given number of words?

Comment: if I do not want user to input stop , or just use space key to exit.

Comment: @Jared Correct! That's the output I want. Thank you.